# Chrome 80 can't install extensions Ubuntu 18.04 without disabling sandbox

Tags: google-chrome

I've recently installed Google Chrome (Version 81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)
) and I can't install extensions unless I run it with the --no-sandbox option (which I'd rather not do). 
Heading to the chrome web store, I click to add an extension and I get an error saying 'image decode failed':
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmse5.png)

Also, in my journal I get the following - which seems to suggest there is some error with the sandbox:

```
Apr 16 18:50:30 desktop i3-gnome-flashback.desktop[7606]: ../../sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/sigsys_handlers.cc:**CRASHING**:seccomp-bpf failure in syscall ../../sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/sigsys_handlers.cc:**CRASHING**:seccomp-bpf failure in syscall 02040204
```

I'm really not sure how to debug this further. I've tried purging and re-installing chrome, deleting the ~/.config and ~/.cache dirs for chrome but no joy. I sometimes get the same error on starting chrome and it will crash but is isn't consistent.

Running kernel 4.15 if that makes any difference.

Comment: "beta" is the issue. Use an alpha version and if that works you would need to take it up with the creator of the extension. "unless I run it with the --no-sandbox option" That means the extension is not supported for that version of Chrome. 'image decode failed' same: extension is not supported. Regarding the error notice: there is another method around this: use the`--disable-seccomp-filter-sandbox` option.

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind I'll try the alpha (chrome stable does the same thing). As for the extension author - it does this for any extension, I can't get a single extension to install. Thanks for the other option I can look into that as well.